What is Subscription as scope in Azure Monitor Workbook KQL query?
I am trying to understand what a Subscription scope in Azure Monitor Workbook in KQL query panel is?
I know Log Analytics brings data from selected Log Analytics Workspace but where is data coming from for a Subscription scope?



where is data coming from for a Subscription scope?

Subscription scope contains logs such as activity logs, diagnostic logs , telemetry, metrics and other types of logs. Azure Monitor gets logs from all the services and resources within the subscription level.
AzureActivity of subscription level :

For example run AzureActivity, to get activity logs:

To get Diagnostic Logs of Subscription:
AzureDiagnostics



Correc.  Log analytics works in 2 ways "workspace centric" where you query a specific workspace (database) and see only the data in that workspace.  there is also "resource centric", where you are asking logs to query all of the logs for a resource (or resource container) across ALL workspaces you potentially have access to.  So for something like "subscription", it is looking for all the logs for any resources in that subscription.
